# MySQL Table with frequent TRUNCATE, UPDATE, & SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an application that requires a MySQL table to be emptied and refilled with fresh data every minute. At the same time, it is expected that the table will receive anywhere from 10-15 SELECT statements per second constantly. The SELECT statements should in general be very fast (selecting 10-50 medium length strings every time). A few things I'm worried about:

Is there the potential for a SELECT query to run in between the TRUNCATE and UPDATE queries as to return 0 rows? Do I need to lock the table when executing the TRUNCATE-UPDATE query pair?

Are there any significant performance issues I should worry about regarding this setup?

Comment: that set up looks bad - what the big picture?

Comment: you think that you are building an application that requires a MySQL table to be emptied and refilled with fresh data every minute. You ultimately won't

Comment: can you describe the high-level business language of what is going on? the hours of the day this is happening? and the need to retain the data if ever? can you show a mocked up table schema? those processes doing inserts, can they be blocked for fractions of seconds? is there a consuming process that obviously decides something like `hey i got the last goop, processed it, now let's empty those` ... the concept as written is quite vague

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why are you trying to do something like this?

Comment: I ended up solving the issue by not TRUNCATING the table. I simply use REPLACE INTO with an md5 hash id and once the table is updated, DELETE old data.

Answer (score -1):

There most propably is a better way to achieve your goal. But here's a possible answer to your question anyway: You can encapsulate queries that are meant to be executed together in a transaction. Off the top of my head something like

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
TRUNCATE foo;
INSERT INTO foo ...;
COMMIT;
```

**EDIT: The above part is plain wrong, see Philip Devine's comment. Thanks.**

Regarding the performance question: Repeatedly connecting to the server can be costly. If you have a persistent connection, you should be fine. You can save little bits here and there by executing multiple queries in a batch or using Prepared Statements.

Comment: Dont do this! Truncate is always done immediately as it is ddl not dml!

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need to truncate it every minute? Yes that will result in your users having no rows returned.  Just update the rows instead of truncate and insert.

A second option is to insert the new values into a new table, rename the two tables as so:

```
RENAME TABLE tbl_name TO new_tbl_name
[, tbl_name2 TO new_tbl_name2]
```

Then truncate the old table.

Then your users see zero down time.  The truncate in the other answer ignores transactions and happens immediately so dont do that!!

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: No, its an answer to the question in the op "  Is there the potential for a SELECT query to run in between the TRUNCATE and UPDATE queries as to return 0 rows? "  and i offered a solution. Read carefully.

Comment: it is against sacred protocol and you will be spanked accordingly

Comment: how does renaming jive with data coming into a table that doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Ok then continue to downvote the only answer that correctly addresses the question.

Comment: You rename the new table name to the old one.. This is very fast, locks the table for transactions... Maybe clarify what you don't understand.

Comment: how does subsequent inserts that explode correctly position this system

Comment: Step 1, insert NEW ROWS to NEW TABLE. step two rename the old table to new, and new table to old.  This is ATOMIC as per spec. Step 3 truncate old table. The users see no difference and its very fast.  All they see are the new rows.

Comment: show it in code with necessary locking so we have a straw man to vote up. i am happy to vote for great answers

Comment: I already did. The statement is atomic as per spec no transaction needed.

Comment: There certainly are merits to this approach for some circumstances. If only the op-guy could engage a question or two to his question we might actually be able to craft proposed thoughts but we will never know i guess will we